# Why onCreate Bundle and onSaveInstanceState Bundle are different in a Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, bundle, restore, oncreate

I have look around but can't find the answer to this exact question.

In an Activity this simple program :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)Log.e("SaveInstanceState", "onCreate Bundle " + savedInstanceState.hashCode()+" " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.e("SaveInstanceState", "onSaveInstanceState Bundle " + outState.hashCode()+" " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());

}
```

Will result in the following output (when I turn the phone orientation):

```
E/SaveInstanceState﹕ onSaveInstanceState Bundle 1110617176 MainActivity
E/SaveInstanceState﹕ onCreate Bundle 1110617176 MainActivity
```

Same Bundle, hence I can easily pass and restore data.

But in a fragment, this code :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)Log.e("SaveInstanceState", "onCreate Bundle " + savedInstanceState.hashCode()+" " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater,container, savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)Log.e("SaveInstanceState", "onCreateView Bundle " + savedInstanceState.hashCode()+" " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.e("SaveInstanceState", "onSaveInstanceState Bundle " + outState.hashCode()+" " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());

}
```

Results in this output :

```
E/SaveInstanceState﹕ onSaveInstanceState Bundle 1110622064 FragmentB
E/SaveInstanceState﹕ onCreate Bundle 1110623448 FragmentB
E/SaveInstanceState﹕ onCreateView Bundle 1110623448 FragmentB
```

The onSaveInstanceState Bundle and the onCreate are different, hence I loose the data stored in the onSaveInstanceState Bundle.

Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong ?

UPDATE

Ok thanks @Sascha Kolberg, the fact that the Bundle Hashcode is different doesn't means the Bundle is empty. 
Then the question become  :

Why can't I retrieve my data from the Fragment onCreate Bundle ?

This is what I do :

```
    public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

        public static final String USER_TEXT = "user_text";
        EditText userText;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
            userText = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.userText);

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                Log.e("SaveInstanceState",
                      "onCreateView savedInstanceState " + savedInstanceState + " " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
                Log.e("SaveInstanceState",
                      "onCreateView savedInstanceState.getString(USER_TEXT) " + savedInstanceState.getString(USER_TEXT) +
                      " " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
                userText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(USER_TEXT));
            }
            return layout;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState = new Bundle();
            outState.putString(USER_TEXT, String.valueOf(userText.getText()));
            Log.e("SaveInstanceState", "onSaveInstanceState outState " + outState + " " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
            Log.e("SaveInstanceState",
                  "onSaveInstanceState outState.getString(USER_TEXT) " + outState.getString(USER_TEXT) + " " +
                  this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }
```

Now, I open my phone, write "Hello!" in the EditText, then clear the logcat, and change orientation of the phone from portrait to landscape.

The output is as follow :

```
E/SaveInstanceState﹕ onSaveInstanceState outState Bundle[{user_text=Hello! }] FragmentB
E/SaveInstanceState﹕ onSaveInstanceState outState.getString(USER_TEXT) Hello!  FragmentB
E/SaveInstanceState﹕ onCreateView savedInstanceState Bundle[{android:view_state={2131492945=TextView.SavedState{423430e0 start=5 end=5 text=Hello!  locale=fr-FR}}}] FragmentB
E/SaveInstanceState﹕ onCreateView savedInstanceState.getString(USER_TEXT) null FragmentB
```

And the EditText is empty after rotating the phone. I guess that I could retrieve the data by doing something like :

```
SparseArray p=savedInstanceState.getSparseParcelableArray("android:view_state");
```

in the onCreate method, but this seems really complicated.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

An Activities *outState* `Bundle` also contains all states of it's child fragments.

So, when the bundle passes a fragment in `onSaveInstanceState()` it might pass its siblings afterwards and in 'onCreate()' contain more than just its own state.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it put me on tracks. My activity is now managing the state of its chid fragments by passing them a Bundle in its onCreate method (fragmentB.setArguments(<the Bundle saved in its onSaveInstanceState>)) and it works, but then I make no use at all of the fragment onSaveInstanceState method. I'm not sure if it is the proper way, but it works so... why look further.

Comment: I don't think you need to do that. Just because the bundles hash code differs, does not mean you loose data. It differs because it contains **more** data, than when you logged it in `onSaveInstanceState`. Have actually looked inside the bundle whether or not your data is there?

Comment: Yes I have look inside, and check it again after your comment.

Comment: Ok, the Bundle contains the data (Hello!). This is the Bundle Bundle[{android:view_state={2131492945=TextView.SavedState{42329e28 start=4 end=4 text=Hello! locale=fr-FR}}}]. This is how I have set it outState=new Bundle();      outState.putString(USER_TEXT,String.valueOf(userText.getText())); I thought I could just retrieve the value by doing savedInstanceState.getString(USER_TEXT) but it return null, there must be another way.

Comment: @ElorriEtchemendy Please add the code where you write and read the data to your question and describe how you test it. Especially how you  ensure that the fragment instance is destroyed and how you re-create it.